# Paypal integration with pocket PC application for Windows mobile 6.0

Tags: .net, compact-framework, paypal, pocketpc

I'm developing a pocket PC application for Windows mobile 6.0 and I want to use Paypal.

Should i use Web Browser control for this. I need to know the entire process and flow to implement PayPal to my smart device application.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what your requirements are, but I would start with the [PayPal web services API](https://developer.paypal.com/en_US/pdf/PP_APIReference.pdf).

Comment: i want to integrate paypal in pocket pc application. if i will have to use paypal web service api, how can i proceed

Comment: Start by going through the documentation I linked to.  That will point you in the right direction.

Comment: IS Paypal webservice api is free and can be implement on .net compact framework